# Force orientation to be Portrait for one view and both for another

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

My design is as follows: Menu -> App -> Back to Menu

I want my Menu to be 'Portrait ONLY'. My AppView can be Portrait & Landscape.

Currently in my MenuController, I have:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

and in my AppView Controller I have:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
}
```

However, my Main menu is rotating in all directions. Anything I am missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to also change it in plist. You change the property in target of the project. Go to Target, in general tab go to deployment info -> device orientation......
Further you need to subclass UINavigationController and override it:

```
-(NSUInteger)suppoertedInterfaceOrientations
{
return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

This will make sure that the viewController being displayed by navigation is in syn

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. I want **one view to be forced portrait** and the **other one to support both orientations**. If I do what you said, I disable the entire app from certain orientations (which is not what i want to do)

Comment: What is you menu cotroller? a UiViewController right? tell the view hierarchy a bit.

Comment: Both my Menu & App are UIViewControllers. However, they are embedded in UINavigationController so that I can segue from Menu to App and then dismiss App to go back to Menu.